# Is there a version of the arcsine rule for biased coins?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm just reading about the arcsine rule for the first time in the context of coin flipping, i.e., that one player is very likely to lead a large percentage of the time in a finite number of trials.

**Question**: Is whether there is a generalized version of this for biased coin?

I tried finding something via a search engine, but a lot of the literature is in the context of academic papers on Brownian motion, so I'm unable to make heads or tails of it (pun unintended).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific regarding *which* arcsine law you are interested in? What you currently describe almost sounds more like the *ballot theorem*. There *are* generalizations to the arcsine law regarding the proportion of intervals between ties in which one player is leading. Note that in an biased coin setting there is a nonnegligible probability of *never* returning to zero.

Comment: I'm only now attempting to learn prob/stat so I'm going to pre-apologize if this isn't clear.

I was reading that in a finite coin flipping/random walk setting that you're very likely to be on one side of 0 for a majority of the steps. And that this probability is given by a formula involving arcsin.

My question was really along the lines of: assume you have a 1/3-2/3 coin, can you state anything about the probability of being on one side of the "new zero"="1/3rd".

I hope that's reasonably coherent.

Comment: Hi Goren. Thanks. Yes, that's helpful in determining what you are interested in and no need to apologize at all! :)